# Need Suggestion to Generate PDF from JSP

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Using JAVA I need to generate PDF from JSP so that the dynamic contents and styles of JSP should be visible in PDF just like exporting JSP page as PDF. Can anyone suggest me the suitable API for that? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iText](http://itextpdf.com/). Brilliant Documentation and examples are provided.

Comment: I edited your answer to the official website http://itextpdf.com, because we're phasing out SourceForge. The git repo is on GitHub: http://github.com/itext/itextpdf

Answer (score 0):

Like html tags a pdf file has a suitable directives, you need to follow the directives of pdf document. view the apendix G (contains examples for creating pdf file) of the following book now

http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_reference_1-7.pdf

place your dynamic content within the stream tags